# Static NextJS dynamic display of components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In React it's simple to use state in order to hide and show (mount and unmount) components in the render function -

```
{this.state.showMyComponent && <MyComponent/>}
```

Is it is possible to use state to do this in a **static** exported NextJS application? i.e. have run `npm run build && npm run export` to create the static artifacts.  However I no longer have any functionality linked to the component `state`, and can no longer toggle a component based in state?  I get that it's a "static" site and what I am trying to do probably not "static" but I'm struggling to understand what NextJS static rendering offers if it cannot handle something so trivial in react?